# Populate limited amount of documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider this sample Schema

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Let's say i have 10 records in MongoDb book collection
When querying list of books i would like to populate only top 3 books

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    Book.find()
        .populate('user', 'displayName') //populate only top 3 books here (10 in db)
        .exec(function(err, books) {
            res.json(books);
        });
};
```

How do i do this?

## Update

I want all 10 documents, but only first 3 to be populated;

Comment: "Top" based on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where the "top three" are meant to come from, but if you just want "three of the books" however you determine that ( and better with a sort ) then you need to work this out so that only "three" of the results are populated and the other results do not get the same treatment.

So instead you do this "inside" the results on only "part" of the array of results:

```js
Book.find().exec(function(err,books) {
    User.populate(
        books.slice(0,3),                            // get first 3 array items
        { "path": "user", "select": "displayName" }, // populate options
        function(err,part) {
            books = part.concat(books.slice(-(books.length-3)));
            console.log( JSON.stringify( books, undefined, 2 ) );
        }
    );
});
```

So as you can see you do that by manually calling the form of `.populate()` from the `User` model, and by taking only "part" of the array response you want to populate and then rejoining it with the whole response.

As a longer working example there is this:

```js
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/poptest');

var items = [
  "one", "two", "three", "four","five",
  "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
];

var itemSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var dataSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }]
});

var Item = mongoose.model( 'Item', itemSchema );
var Data = mongoose.model( 'Data', dataSchema );

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Item,Data],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },

    function(callback) {
      async.each([Item,Data],function(model,callback) {
        async.each(items,function(item,callback) {
          model.create({ name: item },callback);
        },callback);
      },callback);
    },

    function(callback) {
      async.waterfall(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Item.find({ name: { "$in": ["one","two","three"]  } })
              .exec(callback);
          },
          function(itemList,callback) {
            Data.find().exec(function(err,datas) {
              callback(err,itemList,datas);
            });
          },
          function(itemList,datas,callback) {
            async.each(datas,function(data,callback) {
              itemList.forEach(function(item) {
                data.items.push(item._id);
              });

              data.save(callback)
            },callback);
          }
        ],
        callback
      );
    },

    function(callback) {
      Data.find().exec(function(err,data) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        Item.populate(data.slice(0,3),'items',function(err,part) {
          if (err) callback(err);
          data = part.concat(data.slice(-(data.length-3)));
          console.log(data);
          callback()
        });
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which produces output showing only the first three results populated:

```js
[ { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de221e,
    name: 'one',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2214, name: 'one', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2215, name: 'two', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2216, name: 'three', __v: 0 } ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de221f,
    name: 'two',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2214, name: 'one', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2215, name: 'two', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2216, name: 'three', __v: 0 } ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2220,
    name: 'three',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2214, name: 'one', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2215, name: 'two', __v: 0 },
       { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2216, name: 'three', __v: 0 } ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2221,
    name: 'four',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ 55dc369e584563b619de2214,
       55dc369e584563b619de2215,
       55dc369e584563b619de2216 ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2222,
    name: 'five',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ 55dc369e584563b619de2214,
       55dc369e584563b619de2215,
       55dc369e584563b619de2216 ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2223,
    name: 'six',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ 55dc369e584563b619de2214,
       55dc369e584563b619de2215,
       55dc369e584563b619de2216 ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2224,
    name: 'seven',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ 55dc369e584563b619de2214,
       55dc369e584563b619de2215,
       55dc369e584563b619de2216 ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2225,
    name: 'eight',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ 55dc369e584563b619de2214,
       55dc369e584563b619de2215,
       55dc369e584563b619de2216 ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2226,
    name: 'nine',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ 55dc369e584563b619de2214,
       55dc369e584563b619de2215,
       55dc369e584563b619de2216 ] },
  { _id: 55dc369e584563b619de2227,
    name: 'ten',
    __v: 1,
    items:
     [ 55dc369e584563b619de2214,
       55dc369e584563b619de2215,
       55dc369e584563b619de2216 ] } ]
```

Comment: Would be even greater if book population was a bit more easier/nicer (i mean it looks like a d̶i̶r̶t̶y̶ hack), anyway thanks it works like a charm

Comment: @evc Catch is that there is not really anything in the mongoose "syntax sugar" that does specifically what you want, so you need to adapt. Like all "dirty hacks" , the best thing is to "plugin" some functionality and hide the ugly code away, so that in your functional code there is just one clean method call that does the job.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add the `options` property:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    Book.find()
    .populate({
        path: 'user',
        select: 'displayName',
        options: {
            limit: 3
        }
    }) //populate only top 3 books here (10 in db)
    .exec(function (err, books) {
        res.json(books);
    });
};
```

Comment: Well in a way, yes. However your own comment rings true here *"Top based on what?"*, which of course this cannot possibly answer. And also whilst a good example of options to be passed to `.populate()`, it does seem to be the "reverse" of what is generally implied in the question. Therefore the *Top 3* "Books" in the collection are the only things "populated". So again, does the question just want the "top 3 books?" Or does it want "all" the books and just the "top 3" to be populated? So this is correct use of the particular option. But it does not really answer the question posed.

Comment: Tested this, it still populates `user: 'displayName'` for all documents